# Multiple apache subdomains - main domain and subs all same CNAME, IP and PORT. One subdomain works, the other doesn't

Tags: apache, dns, web, subdomain, virtualhost

I am trying to create a setup so that I have the following three domains:

`mydomain.com
files.mydomain.com
mail.mydomain.com`

I have managed to get the first two to work but the third keeps redirecting back to the main domain instead.

In /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ I have three .conf files. The first:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
        ...
</VirtualHost>
```

The second:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName files.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    Alias /media  /home/user/cloud/media
    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

and the third:

```
<VirtualHost .*:80>
     ServerName mail.mydomain.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www
     Alias /mail /usr/share/mail
     ....
</VirtualHost>
```

All three have been a2ensite'd and I have restarted apache2. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dot:

```
<VirtualHost .*:80>
             ^
             ^
             ^
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be something daft that I had missed. Spent good three hours last night trying to figure out what I had done wrong. Can't believe I didn't notice it either when typing up shortened versions of the config files. Thanks again.